# Mapping domain name to linux server

Tags: linux, apache, dns

I bought a domain name with GoDaddy.com. I have a Ubuntu linux server running with Rackspace Cloud. On this server, I have Apache up and running.

My question is this: How can I set up my domain to point to my server with Rackspace Cloud. More specifically, I want http://www.mydomainname.com to map to my Apache server.

I am assuming that I need to establish something with DNS.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a new A record and point `www` to your ip address, eg 69.69.120.200. Also make another A record and point @ to the same IP.

Then make corresponding virtualhosts in Apache with `ServerName domain.com`

Comment: Whit is an A record? How do you create one (in linux)?

Comment: An A record stands for Address Record and it basically maps a logical name like www.mydomain.com or mail.mydomain.com to an IP address. See the list of possible DNS records here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Record

Comment: Here is an article on how to configure the virtual host on your linux machine: http://www.ghacks.net/2009/03/17/adding-a-name-based-virtual-host-in-apache/. Also remember to restart apache after configuring this. Also DNS may take an hour or a few to propagate. So it may not work immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Create the record as meder said, then in the GoDaddy interface you will need to point the name server to the name servers at Rackspace.